# Prepared Insert Query

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code:

```
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Site ID:
        <input type="text" name="site"/>
        </label>
        <label>Location:
        <input type="text" name="location"/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site(site_id, location) values (?,?)");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $site_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $location);


    $site_id = $_POST["site"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    $stmt->execute();



?>
```

I'm getting a null error

I understand the form is trying to submit the data when I go onto the page, so what do I need to do to sort that out?

Comment: didn't you ask the same question a half hour ago?

Comment: Kinda, but I've changed my code

Comment: Did you delete the old question?  It was basically the same question, right?  You could have updated it... it's not that different at all.

Comment: Ok i'll remember that if there's a next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these lines are reversed:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site(site_id, location) values (?,?)");

    $site_id = $_POST["site"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $site_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $location);

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

if you're still getting the `null` error try to debug like this:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site(site_id, location) values (?,?)");

    $site_id = $_POST["site"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    // if $site_id is null (or maybe empty) your PDO will error  
    print "\$site_id is $site_id  <br/>"; 
    print "\$location is $location "; 

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $site_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $location);

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

for debugging, you can check your post variables like this:

```
print "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";
```

I include the `<pre>` so it looks nicer.  This will dump the whole `$_POST` array.  If you're not getting anything, that means that your form or ajax or whatever isn't submitting anything to the page.

---

this works for me:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST))
{
     $user = 'root'; 
     $pass = ''; 

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site (site_id, location) values (?,?)");

    $site_id  = $_POST["site"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $site_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $location);  

    $success = $stmt->execute();  

     if ($success) { print "insert successful"; }
              else { print "not successful"; } 
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Site ID:
        <input type="text" name="site"/>
        </label>
        <label>Location:
        <input type="text" name="location"/>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't downvote me.... OP _just_ posted this question like 20 minutes ago and it was clear they didn't know how to debug really.  I wanted to show them how to include print statements.  The initial error was because `$site_id` was null.

Comment: No difference. Still have the erorr

Comment: What do you mean what is it? It's a column in my table. I want the user to insert the data and then for it to go in the database...

Comment: @YourCommonSense - it was posted at the same time..?  I wrote more and it was posted 30 seconds after the other person.

Comment: @Tom - look at the second section of code I posted.  Include those print statements _before_ the execute or bind.  Tell me what the output says.  I don't think your `$_POST` is getting values.

Comment: @Tom - okay, so your `$_POST` is empty then

Comment: Well... it means that your form or ajax or whatever isn't submitting properly.  Is the code in your question all on one page?

Comment: @tom - I included a working example in my post... it looks like the problem is because of how you defined your `<form>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41744/discussion-between-tom-and-user623952)

Answer (score 0):

the code you need

```
<form method=POST>
<fieldset>
    <label>Site ID:
    <input type="text" name="site"/>
    </label>
    <label>Location:
    <input type="text" name="location"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site(site_id, location) values (?,?)");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST["site"],$_POST["location"]]);
}
```

Comment: you posted the same answer I did only 10 seconds after me!  that means I need to downvote you, right?  because it adds no new info to this post and it's late.

Comment: There is a difference. You don't understand how your code works. I do.

Comment: This gave me an error. However don't worry as @user623952 helped me out.